# Running a GUI-based program remotely on windows using python

Tags: windows, python, remote-control

I need to run a program on a another computer which is solely GUI based. It is closed source so I do not have any way to access the backend, nor any way to send in remote signals using simple text strings or other external control methods. I need to be able to trigger functions that normally require the user to push graphical buttons (start/stop buttons, trigger and give file paths for save-as commands, etc.) in this remote program from a python program on the main system. Is there a general way for me to do this?

Note: The systems involved in my particular case are W7 for the master system running python and W2000 for the remote system (this is due to needing to run an archaic piece of hardware that cannot be put into a newer computer due to needing an ISA bus). Hopefully this won't unduly complicate matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Sukuli](http://www.sikulix.com/) to so this, provided that you can get remote viewing to work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using PyAutoGUI, can be installed with PIP:
https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/